# geom_bar how to make multiple series not stack

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to solve a simple problem, I want to show in dollar terms how revenue, expense and contribution margin would look over a number of years.

However, using geom_bar, the values stack on top of one another.

How do I plot the expense and contribution margin within the revenue bar. Now, I know I can find the net differences between each of the categories and plot but I'm lazy and would like to find out  if there is a more efficient process (surely Hadley must have thought of this)

My working so far:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
              Header = c("Income", "Expenses", "Contribution Margin"),
              FY15 = c(100L, 60L, 40L),
              FY16 = c(110L, 70L, 40L),
              FY17 = c(120L, 80L, 40L)
      )


df %>%
  gather(type, value, -Header) %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = c("FY15", "FY16", "FY17"))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = type, y = value, fill = Header), stat = "identity")
```

Apologies about not being clear the first time round, the output I want is:

```
df %>%
  gather(type, value, -Header) %>%
  spread(Header, value) %>%
  mutate(Expenses = Expenses - `Contribution Margin`,
         Income   = Income - (Expenses + `Contribution Margin`)) %>%
  gather(Header, value, -type) %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = c("FY15", "FY16", "FY17"))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = type, y = value, fill = Header), stat = "identity")
```

However, I'd like to avoid the recalculation done above. I need to present this information over 7 years and for some 10 business units, so real estate space is very limited and it has to look nice and pretty, hence my request.

Comment: Does this do what you want? `geom_bar(aes(x = type, y = value, fill = Header), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")`

Comment: Use `geom_col`. It's short-hand for `geom_bar(..., stat = "identity")`

Comment: @Relasta  - I have updated my question based on your input.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that Contribution Margin is always the sum of Income + Expenses?

If so, just plotting Income and Expenses will create a stacked bar, and the height of the overall bar would indicate Contribution Margin.

```
df %>%
  gather(type, value, -Header) %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = c("FY15", "FY16", "FY17"))) %>%
  filter(Header != "Contribution Margin") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = type, y = value, fill = Header), stat = "identity")
```

[image]

But I also think I'm not really understanding your question. Could you sketch out what you want the final chart to look like?

Comment: When you ask that "so real estate space is very limited and it has to look nice and pretty" - you want the code itself to be shorter/neater? 

Or your chart needs to fit all 10 business units and 7 years' data in one figure? In which case you can use `facet_wrap("unit")` - provided your column identifying business units is named `unit` - to generate 10 small plots within one chart. 

For making it aesthetically "nice and pretty" I'd look at [ggplot's theming capabilities](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html).